# remove comments program from Kernighan and Ritchie

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

This is about the comment deletion program in Kernighan and Ritchie (number 1-23 p 34 ANSI eidtion). The following is my solution.

http://pastebin.com/Fu9C94fV

The program works fine with most C programs, deleting comments. However, in some programs with comments that end with multiple asterisks (******/), it poses problems (does not read through). One such example is this one :

http://pastebin.com/J8EQrwve

However, it works with this program, despite the fact that it has a similar comment at the beginning:

http://pastebin.com/thWKvDS7

So what do you think is causing the comment deletion program to behave this way?

Comment: You seem to have some issues with your whitespace, both the linked-to code and the question (before DevSolar edited it) are over-using it.

Comment: Tried to edit the linked code.. After 2 mins thought better of it..

Comment: Holy wow. It looked at first as though you had a totally broken random placement of closing braces. Then I saw that you lined up the closing brace under the opening brace. Don't do that if you place the opening brace on the same line as the function header/control structure. Line up the closing brace with the first character of the control structure or function type/name (optionally, put the opening brace on a new line in the same column). That makes it far easier to see which block is terminated by which `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit a `*` in comment state, you read the next character to see if it's a `/`. This *consumes* that character, so it won't be checked on the next iteration.

So:

```
/*  **/
    12
```

sees the `*` at 1, reads the `*` at 2, stays in comment mode, and `continue`s with the `/`. Whereas:

```
/* ***/
   123
```

sees the `*` at 2, reads the `*` at 2, continues, then reads the `*` at 3 and finds a `/` following and drops out of comment mode.

Comment: Thanks dude, I introduced another state called star (within a comment). And now it works like a charm. :)